# Могу ли я поднять почтовый сервер без 25 порта?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, dovecot

Хочу развернуть свой почтовый сервер. Купил домен, статический ip. Сертификат взял от Let's encrypt.

Ну PTR запись - пол беды. Мне, в основном, необходимо принимать почту. А вот заблокированный 25 порт (SMTP) - существенная сложность.

Зато, открыт порт 465 (SMTPS). Также, есть классический порт 587 MSA (submission agent).

Смогу ли я сделать при таких условиях сервер?

Comment: Не сможете, потому что весь приём почты идёт конкретно на порт 25

Comment: По стандарту все внешние отправители, найдя ваш сервер по MX записи в DNS, будут пытаться установить соединение на 25 порт. 465 и 587 - это только для клиентских  приложений. Решение в использовании редея (на публичном адресе и с открытым 25 портом), который Бк пересылал почту на открытый порт вашего сервера.

Comment: Попробуйте договориться с провайдером что бы вам открыли 25 порт. Большинство провайдеров идут на встречу и по запросу открывают

Comment: @andreymal тоесть имеющий доступ к проводу может спокойно читать входящую почту и с этим ничего не сделали в эпоху tls?

Comment: @eri внутри этого порта 25 выполняется starttls (если поддерживается обеими сторонами, конечно)

Comment: @eri впрочем, из-за того, что в мире есть множество неправильно настроенных серверов и принудительный starttls никто не включает, имеющий доступ к проводу наверное может просто вырезать объявление starttls 